# Can't add a sprite node

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add a sprite node to the scene with the following code:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"image-hd.png"];
sprite.position = ccp(0, 0);
[self addChild:sprite];
```

and I get the *invalid spriteFrame for sprite* error.
The thing is that I have a sprite sheet for my sprites, but in this example image-hd.png is not a part of it. From what the quick help reads (that it can be both from sprite sheet and from a file), it should be working, but it's not. There is no SD version for image.png, but I thought that cocos2d would recognize the required image resolution depending on the device, the way SpriteKit would, for example. I remember there was a separate method spriteWithFile and spriteWithSpriteFrame, but it looks like they are deprecated in newer versions. Is there a workaround today? (Cocos2d v3.4)

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right path for image?

If you are using spritebuilder, it might be something like this;

```
[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Published-iOS/Game/image.png"]
```

Comment: I tried many paths listed here http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/loading-images-in-code-created-with-spritebuilder/271/6 including some of those I might think of, and none worked. By the way, can it be, that the problem is actually because I only have "image-hd.png", and not "image.png"? I thought this would not be crucial as I will only use devices that are iPhone 4 and older. Can it be the problem?

Comment: @TheDood yes, it is probably looking for a `image-hd-hd.png` file if you are running on a retina something (device or sim). The whole point of cocos2d's name extender is to keep the code constant `image.png` will load the proper image-something.png file for the device.

Comment: So probably because my suffix is not recognized and now I'm using just image.png the image (which is 2x size) appears scaled twice it's size on iPhone 4> as they're automatically recognized as 1x and are resized. I still don't understand this mechanic, someone please explain me how to get it working for iPhone 4> resolutions.

Comment: Nvm, fixed it by completely unlinking SpriteBuilder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101120/cocos2d-v-2-to-v-3-all-my-resources-scale-up-like-crazy)